How do you style inside OL in print media
I am having trouble understanding the CSS required to style a <p> inside an <ol> when using 'print' media.
It works fine on screen but I cannot get an underline in a PDF document.
In the example below, only the paragraphs outside the list appear underlined.  I've tried using ol > p, spans, headings and any other wild stab in the dark I can think of. Somebody please tell me what I'm missing.
I get the same result using Firefox or Edge.
My style sheet is:
@media print {
    #test p {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
    }
}

my html is
<div id="test">
    <p>underline me</p>
    <ol>
        <p>underline me</p>
    </ol>
    <p>underline me</p>
</div>


You should fix your broken HTML first of all - ol is not allowed to have p as a child.

A p is not a permitted child of a ul/ol only li are allowed.

Can't reproduce - https://jsfiddle.net/yjv8qt3d/ shows me a print preview with all three paragraphs underlined. (Can't actually print where I am right now, but I doubt the result would be different than the preview.)

Thank you. I did not realise that p could not be a child as it was working on screen.  That will explain it.  Any idea how I could underline a sub heading within the ordered list?

This clearly looks like a bug, see this snippet:


print()
@media print {
    #test p {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
        color: green;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
}
<div id="test">
    <p>underline me</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <p>underline me</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>underline me</p>
</div>



and the result:

which clearly indicates that the selector is successfully applied on all paragraphs, but the text decoration is not. Here you can see that it's not even related to ol (I of course added a li tag in the previous example)


print()
@media print {
    #test p {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
        color: green;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
}
<div id="test">
    <p>underline me</p>
    <p>underline me</p>
</div>



Result:

So it very much seems that it's not solvable as a developer and instead you will need to send a ticket to the browsers wherever this is not working as expected.
EDIT
Result in Chrome:


@KJ I am using FireFox for stackoverflow. But indeed, in Chromium this appears to be fixed. So, it seems that my code fixed your issue for Chromium, but it does not work under FireFox due to a browser bug. Hence, the answer is that you need a li inside your ol and then the decoration should work and, if it does not work, then the developers of the browser should be notified of a bug. If this answer helped you towards the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

@KJ thanks for the observation, added a screenshot for Chromium. Did not trim down the first two yet, but I will try to remember to do it later today.
